# Exponential inequality with trigonometric functions, same base and different exponents

Tags: exponential-function

$$0.2^{\cos(2x)}-\frac1{25^{\cos^2(x)}}<4\times 125^{-\left(\frac12\right)}$$

I got it down to this:

$$5^{1-2\sin^2(x)}-5^{-2\cos^2(x)}<4\times 5^{-\left(\frac32\right)}$$

I don't know what next.

They all have the same base, but I have a sum on the left side and a coefficient on the right that are preventing me from applying the $\log$ function to both sides.

What do I do here?

The trigonometry isn't the problem here, I just need to remove the exponential part of this in-equation and turn it into what will probably be a quadratic trigonometric inequality.

Conveniently, the $10$ pages of my textbook that  probably deal with this have been ripped out. -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint -

Change $1-2\sin^2x$ into $2\cos^2x-1$. Then try to proceed.

Comment: I've just figured it out.

Comment: P.S. Thanks. =)